How to type check some React Navigation screen options in a nested navigator
I am working on a React Native app that uses React Navigation for routing, and I want to know how to type check the screen options nested navigator. The app is written in typescript I have a bottom tab navigator nested inside a stack navigator and I want to access the navigation prop that is passed to screen options. Here are the types for my routes.
export type RootStackParamsList = {
    ManageExpenses: undefined,
    ExpensesOverview: NavigatorScreenParams<BottomTabsParamsList>
}

export type BottomTabsParamsList = {
    RecentExpenses: undefined,
    AllExpenses: undefined
}

And here is the navigator for the bottom tabs. What I want is to use the navigation prop that is passed to screen options to navigate to the manage expenses screen when the button is pressed in the right header. So basically I want to know how to make typescript happy.
        <BottomTabs.Navigator
            screenOptions={({navigation}: BottomTabNavigationProp<RootStackParamsList, "ExpensesOverview">) => ({
                headerStyle: {backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.primary500},
                headerTintColor: 'white',
                tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.primary500},
                tabBarActiveTintColor: GlobalStyles.colors.accent500,
                headerRight: ({tintColor}) => <IconButton icon={"add"} size={24} color={tintColor!}
                                                          onPress={() => {
                                                              navigation.navi
                                                          }}/>
            })}>
            <BottomTabs.Screen name={"RecentExpenses"} component={RecentExpenses} options={{
                title: "Recent Expenses",
                tabBarLabel: "Recent",
                tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <Ionicons name={"hourglass"} size={size} color={color}/>
            }}/>
            <BottomTabs.Screen name={"AllExpenses"} component={AllExpenses} options={{
                title: "All Expenses",
                tabBarLabel: "Recent",
                tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => <Ionicons name={"calendar"} size={size} color={color}/>
            }}/>
        </BottomTabs.Navigator>

Here is the app.tsx native stack screen navigator.
        <Fragment>
            <StatusBar style={"auto"}/>
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={"ExpensesOverview"}>
                    <Stack.Screen name={"ExpensesOverview"} component={ExpensesOverview}
                                  options={{headerShown: false}}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name={"ManageExpenses"} component={ManageExpenses}/>
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        </Fragment>

I have tried to use the BottomTabNavigationOptions, but for some reason that does not work.
